# Android Tracking Which Async HTTP Call Was Returned

Tags: android, httprequest

In iOS (calm down I'll get to the android part in a second) you can create a `NSURLConnction` and use this object to identify the call that was made:

```
NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Then in the callback code you can say:

```
if (connection == urlConnection)
{
    // this was my urlConnection    
}
else if (connection == urlConnection2)
{
    // this was my urlConnection    
}
```

In Android I have a AsyncTask that runs my HTTP Get request. I also have an interface that calls a `DidFinishConenction` function when the task completes. However, when this is called I need a way to identify which call was made. That way I can handle the result correctly.

In android you can call your AsyncTask with: `new MyServerConnection().execute(myUrl);`

Is there a way to identify this task and compare it to another later similar to iOS?

Thanks,

David

Comment: One way would be adding constructor parameter to your ``MyServerConnection``. E.g you could call it by ``new MyServerConnection(REQUEST_ID).execute(myUrl)`` and later on decide how to handle this particular ``REQUEST_ID``.

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask` doesn't work with call-backs. Rather, you override the task's `onPostExecute` and/or `onProgressUpdate` methods. (You can do your own call-backs from those methods.) You can simply use `==` to compare `MyServerConnection` objects. Alternatively, you can also design your `MyServerConnection` to have an identifier field (that it can generate automatically, if you so desire, or receive as a constructor parameter) and use it for comparison.